# ZFS issues with reboot

Tags: zfs, degraded

After a reboot on Debian 11, I experienced 4 drives that just disappeared for no apparent reason.  2 are 'faulted' and 2 says they are unavailable.

Question:  How do I identify the disks with the numbers given?
EX.

```
   mirror-1                     DEGRADED     0     0     0
      10952364450808395632         UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/sda1
        sdc                        ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-2                     DEGRADED     0     0     0
        sdd                        ONLINE       0     0     0
        3220977116627414992        UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/sdp1
```

Comment: Found out by importing with -d /dev/disk/by-id it converted the numbers to id's understood by the system.  Helpful, but annoying...